# SSH Tunneling and LAMP at same time

Tags: ssh, lamp, ssh-tunnel

I am tunneling Firefox through SSH to a remote server using:

ssh -D 9999 -C usr@remotehost.com

This binds 9999 port on localhost. I set this up in Firefox proxy settings using Socks5. It works perfect. But at same time when I run localhost/myPHPProject, it says 404 not found. Because my localhost IPs (127.0.0.1, 127.1.1.1 etc) are all bound to port 9999 SSH tunnel.

Here's my /etc/hosts

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.0.2   wplms
127.0.1.1   x8p-lin-pc
127.1.1.1   localproxy
```

What I want to do is use localproxy as SSH tunneled proxy for Firefox. And localhost, wplms for my LAMP projects. How is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the -D option bound to a single local IP like so:

```
ssh -D localproxy:9999 -C usr@remotehost.com
```

The harder bit is probably getting firefox to distinguish which connections to send to localproxy and which ones to handle locally.  It might be easier to use a local proxy (squid, varnish, nginx or whatever) to do the forwarding, so you get a more flexible configuration language.

Comment: It worked. Another thing I did is set SOCKS host: localproxy:9999 and No proxy for: localhost, wplms, 127.0.0.1 ...